# Changing legend shapes in Jfree pie chart

Tags: jfreechart, pie-chart

Is it possible to change the legend shapes in the jfree pie chart? I want to add rectangle of different width's as legends in pie chart.

*XYPlot* and *CategoryPlot* has *setFixedLegendItems()* method. Bur *PiePlot* doesn't has this method.

Is it possible to alter the pie chart legends or add new custom legends to jfree pie chart?

[image: Custom legends expected]

Answer (score 2):

This is how I had set it to rectangle, but this would set the all the legends of the same size.

```
    PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();

    plot.setLegendItemShape(new Rectangle(8,6));
    LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();
    legend.setFrame(BlockBorder.NONE);
    legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.RIGHT);
    legend.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP);
```

Comment: Yes. I am aware of this. But I am trying to achieve rectangle legends with multiple width's